# Bathroom exhaust fan/light combo only fan works

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom, exhaust-fan, junction-box

I bought a new bathroom exhaust fan and light combo. It came with two sets of wires, one for the fan and one for the light. It also came with an extra ground for the motor (where should I put that)? So I wired the two hot black wires (one for the fan and one for the light) onto the one red wire for the switch. I then wired all the neutral wires together and all the grounds together, even the one for the motor. This was all done in a junction box with three sets of wires coming in, plus the wires from the fan/light combo. When I turned the breaker back on and flipped the bathroom switch, just the fan came on with no light. All other connections seem secure. Does a fixture like this have to be wired onto two separate switches? I figured just the one would be enough. I am also using LEDS for the lights. The instructions don't even have a number for the company... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One is enough, but a photo might reveal the problem. Your description doesn't. The "extra ground for the motor" doesn't make much sense to me. You might edit to also list the fan model.

Comment: According to your description, the lamp and the fan should be getting the same voltage  If the light is not on, first try an incandescent bulb and if that works try a different LED.  Also check the LED bulb in a different fixture.

Comment: What make and model is this exhaust fan?

Comment: You just have a faulty product like mine. Everything is wired correct. And now I don’t have either fan or light.

Answer (score 1):

You will have a light ground and a fan ground...so read the directions that came with the purchase as it will tell you where to attach the additional ground.  In many cases its a metal strip that the other ground also is attached to... otherwise try contacting the company that manufactured the unit and they have help desks.  But you also may want to hire a qualified person to install that for you...

Comment: Check to make sure the bulb is working.  Then double check your wire nut connections.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of how you wired the circuit both your light and fan should run.  Easiest thing to check is if the bulb was good in another lamp.  The unit you bought could be operated with two independent switches or with one.